# c++ program that finds a type of char* word in a char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cpu-word, match

I have a program  which search through an array to find a word match

```
char *mywords []={"Dog","Cat","etc"};
string search;
cout<<"enter a word to search"<<endl;
cin>>search;
for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
 {
 if(search==mywords[n])
  {
  cout<<mywords[n]<<"found"<<endl; 
  }
 }
```

It works but I am wondering

1. why it doesn't work when I change the part: `string search;` to `char *search=new char;` or `char search[4];` it never finds the word
2. what's the different between `char* word("Dog");`  and  `string word("Dog");` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIRST QUESTION:**

> a) why it doesn't work when I change the part

When you use `char*`, the expression:

```
search == mywords[n]
```

Is comparing two *pointers* of type `char*`, and not the actual zero-terminated strings pointed to by those pointers.

When you use `std::string`, on the other hand, the overloaded `operator ==` that accepts an `std::string` object and a `const char*` pointer is picked, and proper string comparison is performed.

Besides, keep in mind that you always have to `delete` objects allocated with `new`, or you will have a memory leak. This is just another reason why using `std::string` is preferable.

**SECOND QUESTION:**

> b) what's the different between `char* word("Dog");` and `string word("Dog");`

In the first case, you are initializing a pointer `word` to point to the first character of the string literal `"Dog"` - notice, that the type of `word` should be `const char*`, and not `char*`; this implict conversion is deprecated in C++03 and illegal in C++11.

In the second case, you are constructing an object `word` of type `std::string` and passing the `"Dog"` string literal in input to `std::string`'s constructor. The constructor will, in turn, allocate a separate buffer where to *copy* the original string literal passed as an argument.